# RowSpan and colspan table attributes in Repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have table placed inside repeat control and I need to construct the `<xp:td>` tag with rowspan and colspan attributes, where the attribute value changes dynamically. I am not able to find a solution, could you suggest me the best possible solution. Here is my scenario -

Basically I need to show a table quarterly wise where the row span changes, based on selection of start date and end date. for e.g.

Start Date : 1-Feb-2013   and End Date : 30-Dec-2013
     -

Comment: I edited your question, but it is still unclear what exactly is your problem!

Comment: shibu: a year has 4 quarters, a quarter has 3 month... regardless of they year. The only use case I can imagine is: if the start date is in the middle of a quarter (second or third month), show only 1 or two lines for that quarter -- which might actually not be the business case

Comment: Stwissel:This was an example to show how a rowspan changes, when a table is constructed. For eg, 1st Row :<tr><td rowspan=2>Q1</td><td>Feb</td></tr> 2nd Row: <tr><td>Mar</td></tr> . If you place the first row alone in the repeat control and try to compute the rowspan and colspan attribute using a function you would not get the desired result.The output HTML generated by repeat control would be 1st Row :<tr><td rowspan=2>Q1</td><td>Feb</td></tr> 2nd Row: <tr><td rowspan=2>Q1</td><td>Mar</td></tr> .

Answer (score 0):

In "All Properties" of a `<xp:td>` you find rowspan and colspan. Both attributes can be computed. I suggest you compute that in a function you call with some parameter th be handed over. You might need a `requestScope` or `viewScope` object to keep track of your row/col span usage. use JSON for it, makes things easier.

Hth